# My webview reloads when bluetooth disconnects or reconnects

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, android-webview

I have an app that has an issue with bluetooth devices. When i disconnect or reconnect a bluetooth device the app seems to reload or i would say reload webview. It doesn't crash the app because I'm catching the connects and disconnects using the a receiver. Here is the code I'm using and where I'm stuck at. The toast are working and i can't figure out why its refreshing the entire view.

```
public class MyBTReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "BT connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(intent.getAction().equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED"))
        {
        Toast.makeText(context, "BT disconnect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

<receiver android:name=".MyBTReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the bluetooth device is HID then it is triggering a "keyboard" configuration change event which restarts the activity, similar to orientation changes. Add a configChanges="keyboard|screenSize" to your AndroidManifest.xml. I also have keyboardHidden in there for slideout keyboards, along with orientation since I don't want to reload my page when the device is rotated.

Comment: You are correct on the place I needed to look. It ended up being I needed to add navigation to that since the device was d-pad type device. Thanks